# there is an text overflow in my css project

Tags: html, css, web, deployment, frontend

I'm making a food & restaurant website with html & css only and my body is overflowing
in responsive design.

I tried several ways to detect which element is overflowing
ex:- `overflow-x:hidden & overflow-wrap:break-word`.

but i didn't reach anto anything
can any one help me in solving this proplem ?
[here is a screenshot for the website in responsive
Note! It's only in my local because I didn't upload it on github
so, if anyone can text me in messages here I will appreciate that]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wv3FV.png)

overflow-x:hidden,overflow-wrap:break-word,and I also tried to comment some of my Images in Html but nothing happened

Comment: We need to see some code :). Please edit your question to provide just enough (not all) of the code you wrote that reproduces the issue.  Use a stack snippet in the question menu (looks like this: `<>` ) so we can render the code example to debug.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.